# Geometric meaning of unimodular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, gm.general-mathematics

Rotations are given by unitary matrices.

What is the geometric meaning of unimodular matrices that are not unitary?

Comment: volume preserving...

Answer (score 8):

If the matrix has integer elements, then the geometric meaning is that a [unimodular transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnimodularTransformation.html) maps the integer lattice onto itself:

> Consider a basis $B$ of an $m$-dimensional lattice
>   $L(B)=\{Bx:x\in\mathbb{Z}^m$}, and another basis $C$, then $L(B)=L(C)$
>   if and only if there exists a unimodular matrix $M$ (an $m\times m$
>   matrix with integer entries and determinant $\pm 1$) such that $B=CM$.

Comment: @Arul If I understand you correctly, you are wrong. Consider $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$.